# liboppcmdenvd.dll is missing

Tags: dll, omnet++

I have created one project in Omnet++ and now I want to run that project like we run shortcuts. I am trying to execute the .exe file using the cmd prompt it is showing me the system error "The program can't start because liboppcmdenvd.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem". I reinstalled the program but still it is showing the same error. So can anyone please tell me what is that .dll file and how I resolve this error? And also is there any way or any command to run the project without opening the Omnet++?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That file is part of the OMNeT++ simulator. It should be present in your `<omnetpp_root>/bin` directory provided that you correctly installed (and compiled OMNeT++).

Check if the file is present in the `bin` directory. If yes, then check also that the `<omnetpp_root>/bin` is in your path.

If the simulation runs fine from the IDE, but does not from the command line then you are missing the bin directory from your path... Or simply use the provided mingwenv.cmd to start your command prompt and use that to run the simuation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the bin directory and the file is present there and also I have tried to run the program from the mingwenv.cmd. I got error as "<!> Error: NED type `wireless1.Wireless1' could not be fully resolved, due to a missing base type or interface." I have 2 questions now, 1) Can you please tell how to how to include bin directory from my path? 2) How to solve the mentioned error?